# how to disable world light source

Tags: lighting

I am new in blender. I made a scene whose lightning effect is perfect every object is clearly visible when the world background is removed.

but when I change the world color to white it effects the whole environment and add extra white light which in not needed at all.

I tried a lot to find out solution but failed. please assist if any know the proper  solution weather in evee or in cycle in blender 2.8.

clarifying question again 
I want to change the world from black to white but want to disable the white light of the world. thanks

Answer (score 1):

In Cycles click on the *World* tab and in *Ray Visibility* only keep *Camera* enabled. This way the world will be visible but won't light your objects.

[image]

In Eevee (also works in Cycles) you need to create a material for your *World* with an *Input > Light Path (Diffuse output)* as factor of a *Mix Shader*:

[image]

Comment: does'nt work, ambient light is still there

Comment: It doesn't work in Eevee, in Eevee you need to create a material for your World with an Input > Light Path as factor